# Price for a soda has a standard deviation of $\$1.00$ with an expected price of $\$3.00$

Tags: probability, variance, standard-deviation

At a shop, the price doesn't vary but it varies independently between shops. If I buy two sodas from the same shop what the expected price and standard deviation? If my friend buys two sodas from two **different** shops what's the expected price and standard deviation?

**What I have attempted**

I am thinking **my** expected price is $E(3)+E(3)=\$6.00$ for my expected price of soda,

my standard deviation is: $1^2+1^2=\sqrt 1$ so $1.414$

**My friend's is:**
expected price $E(3)+E(3)=\$6.00$ for her expected price of coffee,

her standard deviation is: $1^2+1^2=\sqrt1$ so 1.414

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If a shop has a constant price, then why do you get any non-zero value for $\sigma$?  (your friend buys from two different shops so it makes sense that she gets $\sigma\neq 0$) Also, when I edited your post I left your equations $1^2+1^2=\sqrt 1$ just as you typed them but they are nonsense.

Comment: Because the buyer doesn't know what the store's cost might be... could be high... could be low.  Hence $\sigma \neq 0$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Oh,, maybe that;s what was meant.  I was thinking the OP meant the variation between the two prices.  I expect you are right.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as David. I added my line of thinking to see if someone came to the same conclusion. Would it make sense that we would have the same σ and expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prices $\ F_1, F_2\ $ your friend pays for her cups of coffee are independent random variables each with mean $\ \$3\ $ and standard deviation $\ \$1\ $, so the total cost $\ F_1+F_2\ $ she pays will have mean $\ \$6\ $ and standard deviation $\ \$\sqrt{2}\ $, as you have surmised.

The prices $\ Y_1,Y_2\ $ you pay for *your* cups of coffee, however, are *not* independent, because $\ Y_2=Y_1\ $.  While the total cost $\ 2Y_1\ $ you pay for your cups of coffee also has a mean of $\ \$6\ $, its standard deviation is $\ \$2\ $, *not* $\ \$\sqrt{2}\ $.

Comment: The intuition here is that your total price paid can vary more wildly than that paid by your friend. This is because if your first cup is cheap, then your second cup is also cheap, making the total deviate more from the mean. On the other hand, if your friend's first cup is cheap, there's a chance that his second cup will be expensive which cancels out some of the deviation.